# After IP change on server java.io.IOException: replica.getGenerationStamp()

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am loading data to HDFS using flume. Recently there was a IP change on the server so after that i am not able to start the slaves at all. I have lots of data on the server and data node so reformat is not an option. Even though the master makes a call to slave and tried to start the slave node does not start. Following is the exception i see because slave is still trying to refer to old IP of master:

```
java.io.IOException: replica.getGenerationStamp() < block.getGenerationStamp()
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.InterDatanodeProtocol: Failed to obtain replica info for block (=BP-967573188-192.168.XX.XX-1413284771002:blk_1073757987_17249) from datanode (=192.168.XX.XX:50010)
java.io.IOException: replica.getGenerationStamp() < block.getGenerationStamp(), block=blk_1073757987_17249, replica=ReplicaWaitingToBeRecovered, blk_1073757987_17179, RWR
  getNumBytes()     = 81838954
  getBytesOnDisk()  = 81838954
  getVisibleLength()= -1
  getVolume()       = /var/hadoop/data/current
  getBlockFile()    = /var/hadoop/data/current/BP-967573188-192.168.XX.XX-1413284771002/current/rbw/blk_1073757987
  unlinked=false
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.initReplicaRecovery(FsDatasetImpl.java:1613)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.initReplicaRecovery(FsDatasetImpl.java:1579)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initReplicaRecovery(DataNode.java:2094)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.callInitReplicaRecovery(DataNode.java:2105)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.recoverBlock(DataNode.java:2173)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.access$400(DataNode.java:140)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$2.run(DataNode.java:2079)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have updated the config file /etc/hosts but without any effect. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

update the new Ip address of datanode in slaves file in hadoop conf directory.

Regards
Jyoti Ranjan Panda

Comment: done that but did not work, so i reformatted everything afresh :(. Also the dfs.data.dir had the old IP file created so was there any way to fix that part. Am still interested in knowing